# Django - Accessing static/media files always from a remote MEDIA_URL instead of local one during development

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-media, python-django-storages

I have a Django app running on a server and I would like to continue working on it locally with the `runserver` command. My problem concern the use of *common static and media files*. The **media** folder content changing frequently in production I have to download those media files from the server each time I want to dev locally and add those to the `MEDIA_ROOT` path on my computer.

The database is common to both dev and production environment since it is a MySQL host on my server.

How can I tell Django in local mode to lookup static and media files on a remote url from my domain name instead of localhost?
Like `https://example.com/media/` instead of :
`https://127.0.0.1:8000/media/`

**EDIT : module django-storages**

After some time I finally find a module which seems aligned with what I'm looking for, django-storages with its 'FTP' functionnality' however the [documentation](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/ftp.html) is really weak and I can't find any tutorial explaining what I want to achieve.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.ftp.FTPStorage'
FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'ftp://user:password@host:21/media'
```

What kind of configuration should I add to my settings file to get MEDIA_ROOT looking for this location when I'm working locally ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why `static` files have to be treated the same - they are supposed to be a part of your project **sources**. So local storage should have a higher priority.

But serving any of such files is still just URL dispatching, so instead of this:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

you might try something like this:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path(settings.MEDIA_URL + "<path:file_path>", RedirectView.as_view(url="https://example.com/media/%(file_path)"))
]
```

(did not test it)

[RedirectView docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) [almost similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875281/django-url-patterns-to-serve-external-webpack-bundle)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your solution and some variant and unfortunately it doesn't work :/ . Additional information all files path in DB already start with 'media/'.

Comment: `it doesn't work`, `it did not help` do not help helping you. Please update your question with modified urls.py, show your settings.py and any template referencing those images. And add error details.

Answer (score 0):

**You simply test in after main url**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                  document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
else:
   Production
```

Comment: Thanks for your message, however it is not my question what I want to know is how to tell Django to get a media with its url/path on an existing url on the internet instead of looking in my local media dir.